# nvram boot-args to boot in target disk mode

Tags: startup, nvram

I'd like a Mac to always boot in target disk mode. Similarly to setting

```
sudo nvram boot-args="-v"
```

which boots in *verbose* mode, I tried

```
sudo nvram boot-args="-t"
```

but to no avail. Any idea?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a boot argument for this. [See this list of boot-args on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/255176/is-there-a-list-of-available-boot-args-for-darwin-os-x)

Comment: See @ScottEarle's answer below. Thanks for the list though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this (very useful!) page : http://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-manage-os-x-boot-options-with-wireless-keyboards/

I found the answer you want. And I quote:

> The "boot-args" variable can be used for setting the above modes. but in addition if you need to load the system into Target Disk mode, you can do so by setting the "target-mode" PRAM variable in the following way (this will be enabled only once for the next time the system is started):
>
> ```
> sudo nvram target-mode=1
> ```

It looks like you can't get it to do that on every boot - but you could write a startup script that waited for a minute then set that parameter again then rebooted. Note that without the delay, you would never be able to boot the machine again :)

Then if you ever did want to start the machine not in Target Disk Mode, you would simply kill the startup script while it was waiting for the minute.

Comment: Thanks for the `target-mode=1` parameter. It's unfortunate that you cannot get it to boot in target disk mode indefinitely. Regarding _Note that without the delay, you would never be able to boot the machine again_ I'd say that zapping the NVRAM with the ⌘⌥+P+R should allow you to boot again in normal mode. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Putting it in target mode *forever* would mean you could never get it out again. Hence my suggestion of a startup script with a delay ...

Comment: _Putting it in target mode forever would mean you could never get it out again_ how about zapping the nvram as I wrote above?

Comment: Oh. Yes. Good point. Haha :)

Comment: I hear your startup-script idea, but I have two Mac mini servers (say A and B), with A in target disk mode and B running the show. Now their disks are in a mirrored RAID 1. So if A starts-up and boots normally, then restarts in target disk mode, B will have booted and it'll be too late for the RAID to be connected. Plus, the RAID would have to be reconstructed, which takes ages. That's why I need it to boot in target disk mode perpetually.

Comment: You could write another script (sorry) that made sure that the RAID array was only mounted after A was ready?

Comment: Interesting. So B would have to ``wait'' for A to be ready? Do you have any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: **Lingon** is a helpful GUI for creating a startup-script: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/?source=pdlp